# Ubuntu on VirtualBox crashes when laptop goes to hibernate

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

I am running VirtualBox 5.0.14 on Windows 10. I am running Ubuntu Desktop (I tried 14.04, 15.10 and 16.04 (pre release)) in my VirtualBox environment. When my laptop goes to hibernate the Ubuntu session crashes with the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c6nL.jpg

In case image is not available, the error is:

> The instruction at 0x00007FF92F74E80B referenced memory at
>   0x0000000000000014. The memory could not be read.

I installed the latest version of the Guest additions. How to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernating a host will not hibernate a virtual guest too. Depending on the guest's state this will lead to issues or even data loss.

For some people the [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) will take care of most, others can't hibernate a host at all when a guest is running.

We should therefore [put the guest in savestate mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63524/whats-the-best-way-to-pause-my-work-in-virtualbox-with-ubuntu-as-a-guest) before we hibernate a host.

Putting a guest to savestate can be done from the command line or a script. We could therfroe add it to the host's hibernating routine.

Comment: Indeed, guest additions took care of that before (I was working on a new laptop).  Sounds to me like unnecessary complex and error prone to put the guest in savestate mode. I guess I should log a bug for the VBox guest additions?

Comment: I had a quick look for similar reports there, but I couldn't find one that exactly matches your issue on Windows 10... so yeah, it may be worth reporting to the VBox people.

Comment: Xref: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15151