# Computer is locking when going into sleep mode

Tags: 16.04, suspend

When my system goes into sleep mode, then entire machine is locking up.  Shaking the mouse, pressing keys, or turning the screen on and off has not worked.  The only thing that can resolve the issue is physically turning the machine off and on again.  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: We can't really help at all unless you give us your machine's specs...

Comment: It's a virtual machine running on: 4 GB of memory, Intel® Core™2 CPU 6600 @ 2.40GHz × 2 Processor, 64-bit.  What other information do you need?

Comment: I see. If you're using a VM, why not just use Virtualbox's or VMware's "save machine state" function?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63524/whats-the-best-way-to-pause-my-work-in-virtualbox-with-ubuntu-as-a-guest

Comment: I work under the system admin and he wants me to find a general fix for all the virtual machines, not just for my specific instance.  Can you set this for all of them?

Comment: Absolutely, unless you are running them though KVM or something else that isn't VMware or Virtualbox...